# Asp.net:How to fix exception thrown when sending mail message to multiple recipients?erroline:An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Error on this line `message.To.Add(mailTo);` when I try to take the email data from the database to send an email.

```
 void Sendmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<DAL.Customer> mailId = (from rs in General.db.Customers
                                         where rs.IsActive == true
                                         select rs).ToList();

            StringBuilder mailstring = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var item in mailId)
                {

                        mailstring.Append(item.Email).Append(",");

                }

            string mailTo = mailstring.ToString();

            if (mailTo.EndsWith(","))
            {

                mailTo = mailTo.Remove(mailTo.LastIndexOf(","));
            }


            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            mailMessage.From = fromMail;
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailTo));

            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;



            lblStatus.Text = "Email sent successfully";



    }
```

Comment: Do you really have to indicate the receivers in a comma separated string? Why not just loop the email addresses and send them individually?

Comment: Per MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8.aspx) - `MailAddress(string)` takes a "A String that contains an e-mail address."  Note that it's an e-mail address - singular.  To add multiple addresses, use a loop as @ChristianMark suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this. I don't know the credentials so I assume you can add them up.

```
void Sendmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<DAL.Customer> mailId = (from rs in General.db.Customers
                                         where rs.IsActive == true
                                         select rs).ToList();

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            mailMessage.From = fromMail;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            foreach (var item in mailId)
            {
               mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(item.Email));
            }
            lblStatus.Text = "Email sent successfully";

    }
```

Comment: This can be simplified further by simply doing `mailMessage.To.Add(item.Email)`. For reference though - it *is* possible to pass a comma-delimited list with the `MailMessageCollection.Add(string)` overload.

Answer (score 0):

As Christian Mark suggests, you should probably just loop through each of the mail addresses and add them individually (since you are already looping through them to build a string).

However, the reason why this doesn't work in theory is because you are creating a *single* `MailAddress` with a comma-separated string of email addresses, with the following line:

```
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailTo));
```

You *can* pass a comma-separated list to the `Add(string)` overload of `MailAddressCollection.Add` but - because you are passing a `MailMessage` - this is not the overload you are using.

The following would work:

```
mailMessage.To.Add(mailTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any overload of the `MailAddress` constructor that takes a comma-delimited string.  You need to loop through all the destination e-mail addresses one at a time, which will require a minor reorganization of your code:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
mailMessage.From = fromMail;

List<DAL.Customer> mailId = (from rs in General.db.Customers
                             where rs.IsActive == true
                             select rs).ToList();

foreach (var item in mailId)
{
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(item.Email));
}
```